# Covariance between exogenous variables

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

I am new to SEM and am finding my way around Amos. I am wondering if exogenous variables always have to be declared as covarying even if there is no theoretical reason why they should and they are uncorrelated? If they do as appears to be the case in other research why is this?

Comment: Yes, is the short answer.